# Как проверить доступность CUDA компе?

Tags: c++, cuda

На котором возможно даже нету CUDA и даже нету видеокарты

Comment: лучше если даже без CUDA API

Comment: В таком случае проверяйте доступность nvcc в таком случае. Есть - значит cuda доступна

Comment: Отнюдь не всегда это так ...